# jQuery find() vs. filter() with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to refresh content on a div only when a user submits a form. The page is .php, and the action= is on the same page. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        if($_POST['user'] === 'mysecret' && $_POST['pass'] === 'page')
            $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['auth']))
    {
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <div id="anothercontainer"> </div>
        <div id="container">
        <p id="mycontent"> Here is my new content </p> </div>
        </body> 
        </html>
        <?php
        exit();
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form id="changing" action="test3.php" method="POST">
            User:
            <input type="text" name="user" />
            Pass:
            <input type="password" name="pass" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />

        </form>
        <div id="content"> Here is the content to be updated </div>

        <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#changing').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $content = $('#content');
                    var details = $('#changing').serialize();
                    $.post('test3.php', details, function(data) {
                            $content.html( $(data).find('#container') );
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should refresh content on `#content div`. However, it does nothing. But if I use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`, it works fine.

My question is... why this doesn't work? It has something to do with the PHP or something like this?

I read from Jon Duckett's book... he used `.find()` and it worked. The only difference I saw was it's a .html page instead of .php. The code is like this (ajax request):

```
success: function(data) {                               // Show content
  $content.html( $(data).find('#container') ).hide().fadeIn(400);
},
```

(the full .js code is here: http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/js/jq-ajax.js).
Could somebody help me? Because I'm really confused. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: .find will search the children elements, where as filter will search the already selected elements.